# Why parent process doesn't exit automatically after running a detached child?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

*Node.js 8.9.1, Linux version 4.10.0-42-generic*

Parent

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const forked = fork('child.js', {
  detached: true,
  stdio: 'ignore'
});

const config = {
  name: 'trex',
  interval: 2000
};

forked.send(config);
forked.unref();

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log('do staff');
}
```

Child

```
const work = function() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
};

const start = function(config) {
  setTimeout(function run() {
    work();
    setTimeout(run, config.interval);
  }, config.interval);
};

process.on('message', function(config) {
  start(config);
});
```

I need the parent to start the child and exit normally. Now if I execute `node parent.js` I see the parent still running.

```
trex@beast-cave:~/dev/$ ps aux | grep -e "parent\|child" | grep node
trex      5134  0.0  0.1 874016 29460 pts/11   Sl+  10:44   0:00 node parent.js
trex      5140 86.3  0.1 874108 30252 ?        Rsl  10:44   4:59 /home/trex/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node child.js
```

I know there is `process.exit()`. But why it doesn't exit normally? In my app parent is inside the `setTimeout` loop, there is a lot of logic and it must be run only once in an interval of time.

Comment: Use `forked.unref()`, after your `forked.send()`

Comment: @Keith tried, nevertheless, the parent is still running.

Comment: Just tried it here in windows and seems to work, you still got the `detached:true` ?..  You could maybe also try -> `stdio: 'ignore'` in case it's stdio keeping things referenced.

Comment: @Keith yes, I still have it with `detached` option, no success. Look for the code update in the question.

Comment: Just copy pasted your code and tried again, get `do staff` console logged 3 times, and back to the console.  And the child process still running taking a fair chunk of CPU.  I'm on node version `v8.9.0`,.. windows.. Looking at the docs for detached there is some subtle difference between Linux & windows so maybe something there.  So other idea's, maybe it's the way the IPC channel work in Linux, maybe try and not use `forked.send()` and see if it still happens..  If that works maybe pass paramenters using arguments instead of IPC.

Comment: @Keith tried without `forked.send()`, no success

Comment: This is strange, maybe something to contact `node` dev's about.  Your example code is nice and simple for them to test with.  You can let them know windows it works fine.  Although it shouldn't be required, in the mean time I can't see any harm in using `process.exit()`, I use it without any issues..  Maybe place the `process.exit()` inside a setTimeout though, just to make sure the process has time to send the IPC request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html documentation:

> subprocess.disconnect()# Added in: v0.7.2 Closes the IPC channel
>   between parent and child, allowing the child to exit gracefully once
>   there are no other connections keeping it alive. After calling this
>   method the subprocess.connected and process.connected properties in
>   both the parent and child (respectively) will be set to false, and it
>   will be no longer possible to pass messages between the processes.
>
> The 'disconnect' event will be emitted when there are no messages in
>   the process of being received. This will most often be triggered
>   immediately after calling subprocess.disconnect().
>
> Note that when the child process is a Node.js instance (e.g. spawned
>   using child_process.fork()), the process.disconnect() method can be
>   invoked within the child process to close the IPC channel as well.

```
const work = function() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
};

const start = function(config) {
  setTimeout(function run() {
    work();
    setTimeout(run, config.interval);
  }, config.interval);
};

process.on('message', function(config) {
  start(config);
  process.disconnect();
});
```